# Moodle Quickform adding elements in foreach loop not submitting

Tags: php, pear, moodle, quickform

I am making a form from database fields, so I pull all the records and loop through and add the form elements in a foreach loop in php. The problem is when I submit the form the elements are not posted, the only return I get is the submit button: -

```
stdClass Object
(
    [submitbutton] => Submit
)
```

This is how I create the elements, these all display and fucntion correctly onscreen, it just does not post when I submit, but the elements do post if I don't have them in the foreach loop, but I need to create them dynamically from the database, any ideas?

```
foreach($records as $log){
        $inc++;

        if($log->type == 0){ 

            $mform->addElement('html', '<p>'.$log->leadin.'</p>');

            $attributes = array();
            $distractors = explode(',', $log->distractors);
            $radioarray=array();
            $count = 0;

            foreach($distractors as $dis){
                $count++;
                $radioarray[] =& $mform->createElement('radio', 'radio', '', $dis, $count, array());
            }

            $mform->addGroup($radioarray, 'radioar'.$inc, '', array(' '), false);
        }
        else if($log->type == 1){

            $mform->addElement('html', '<div>'.$log->leadin.'</div>');

            $distractors = explode(',', $log->distractors);
            $count = 0;

            foreach($distractors as $dis){
                $count++;
                $mform->addElement('checkbox', 'check'.$count, $dis);
            }
        }}
```

Complete form code: -

```
class build_user_survey extends moodleform{
public function definition() {
    global $CFG;
    global $DB;
    global $OUTPUT;

    $mform =& $this->_form;
    $errors= array();
    $br = "<br />";
    $select = '';
    $records = $this->_customdata['thequestions'];
    $inc = 0;
    $attributes=array('rows'=>'10','cols'=>'80');
    $mform->addElement('hidden', 'id');
    $mform->setType('id', PARAM_INT);
    $mform->addElement('hidden', 'viewpage');
    $mform->setType('viewpage', PARAM_INT);
    $mform->addElement('hidden', 'pickedsurvey');
    $mform->setType('pickedsurvey', PARAM_INT);
    $mform->addElement('hidden', 'questiontype');
    $mform->setType('questiontype', PARAM_INT);


     foreach($records as $log){
        $inc++;

        if($log->type == 0){ 

            $mform->addElement('html', '<div>'.$log->leadin.'</div>');

            $distractors = explode(',', $log->distractors);
            $count = 0;

            foreach($distractors as $dis){
                $count++;
                $mform->addElement('radio', 'radio'.$inc, '', $dis, $count, array());
            }
        }
        else if($log->type == 1){

            $mform->addElement('html', '<div>'.$log->leadin.'</div>');

            $distractors = explode(',', $log->distractors);
            $count = 0;

            foreach($distractors as $dis){
                $count++;
                $mform->addElement('checkbox', 'check'.$count, $dis);
            }
        }
        else if($log->type == 2){
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('here');</script>";
            $thename = 'answer';
            $mform->addElement('textarea', $thename, $log->leadin, $attributes);
        }  
    } 
   foreach($records as $log){
        $mform->addElement('radio', 'radio', '', 'ioh;', 0, array());
   }

    $mform->addElement('textarea', 'answerWorking', '$log->leadin', $attributes);
    $this->add_action_buttons($cancel = true, $submitlabel='Submit');
}
public function validation($data, $files) {
    global $DB;
    $errors= array();
    if($data['id']) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! I found that the extra parameter I was passing in the URL when the page is first loaded and the form is first created also needed to be present when the form is submitted, so the extra parameter on the url searched for a database record, and when I submitted the form, the page gets reloaded and all the functions get called again and fails because the parameter is missing and the records are not found. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox will only return a value if its selected.

Use the advanced check box if you want unselected values too

```
$mform->addElement('advcheckbox', 'check'.$count, $dis);
```

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/lib/formslib.php_Form_Definition#advcheckbox

EDIT : I just copied the code and changed checkbox to advcheckbox and it works :) You will also need to put the $count = 0 before the for loop.

Calling code

```
$thequestions = array();

$thequestion = new stdClass();
$thequestion->type = 1;
$thequestion->leadin = 'leadin 1';
$thequestion->distractors = 'dis1, dis2, dis3';
$thequestions[] = $thequestion;

$thequestion = new stdClass();
$thequestion->type = 1;
$thequestion->leadin = 'leadin 2';
$thequestion->distractors = 'dis4, dis5, dis6';
$thequestions[] = $thequestion;

$mform = new build_user_survey(null, array('thequestions'=>$thequestions ));

if ($data = $mform->get_data()) {
    var_dump($data);
}
$mform->display();
```

Var dump

```
object(stdClass)[3270]
  public 'id' => int 0
  public 'viewpage' => int 0
  public 'pickedsurvey' => int 0
  public 'questiontype' => int 0
  public 'check1' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'check2' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'check3' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'check4' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'check5' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'check6' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'radio' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'answerWorking' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'submitbutton' => string 'Submit' (length=6)
```

Modified form code

```
class build_user_survey extends moodleform {
    public function definition() {


        $mform =& $this->_form;

        $records = $this->_customdata['thequestions'];
        $inc = 0;
        $attributes=array('rows'=>'10','cols'=>'80');
        $mform->addElement('hidden', 'id');
        $mform->setType('id', PARAM_INT);
        $mform->addElement('hidden', 'viewpage');
        $mform->setType('viewpage', PARAM_INT);
        $mform->addElement('hidden', 'pickedsurvey');
        $mform->setType('pickedsurvey', PARAM_INT);
        $mform->addElement('hidden', 'questiontype');
        $mform->setType('questiontype', PARAM_INT);

        $count = 0;
         foreach($records as $log){
            $inc++;

            if($log->type == 0){

                $mform->addElement('html', '<div>'.$log->leadin.'</div>');

                $distractors = explode(',', $log->distractors);

                foreach($distractors as $dis){
                    $count++;
                    $mform->addElement('radio', 'radio'.$inc, '', $dis, $count, array());
                }
            }
            else if($log->type == 1){

                $mform->addElement('html', '<div>'.$log->leadin.'</div>');

                $distractors = explode(',', $log->distractors);

                foreach($distractors as $dis){
                    $count++;
                    $mform->addElement('advcheckbox', 'check'.$count, $dis);
                }
            }
            else if($log->type == 2){
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('here');</script>";
                $thename = 'answer';
                $mform->addElement('textarea', $thename, $log->leadin, $attributes);
            }
        }
       foreach($records as $log){
            $mform->addElement('radio', 'radio', '', 'ioh;', 0, array());
       }

        $mform->addElement('textarea', 'answerWorking', '$log->leadin', $attributes);
        $this->add_action_buttons(true, 'Submit');
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes i have given this a go, but it seems to still not work, have you seen or know if $mform->addElement works within a foreach loop? When i use it in the loop it displays and the html get written correctly, but when you submit the $form->get_data() returns only the submit button, when $mform->addElement is not in the foreach loop it returns as it should do, any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the complete form code? One thing is that the count = 0 needs to be set before the foreach ($records as $log) loop otherwise you will get duplicate element names.

Comment: I have added the complete form code, i invoke this with $form = new build_user_survey(null, array('thequestions'=>$thequestions, 'thesurvey'=>$thesurvey ));